# Parallax effect not working in some browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

Hi guys I am doing this parallax effect with CSS and HTML only. I am testing it for Desktop and it works on: Chrome, Firefox, IE and Spartan.

But I hit on the rock in the mobile test. Currently from my nexus 5:

Firefox: works;
Chrome: not-working;

It is working on Chrome for iOS (for now tested on ipad mini only)

Is this a bug in the version? or I am missing something?

here is a live preview:

[live demo](http://konstantindichev.com/test/index.html)

here is a js file I extracted for you to test:

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/aatpa7qd/)

```
<div id="title" class="slide header"></div>
<div class="slide"></div>

.slide {
   position: relative;
   min-height: 100vh;
   width: 100vw;
}

#title {
   background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/LzOCzLr.jpg");
   background-attachment: fixed;  
}
```

**UPDATE: NOT WORKING ONLY ON CHROME MOBILE IN ANDROID**

Comment: How would that give a parallax effect in FireFox anyways?  That's just a fixed effect.  Which appears to work fine on my Chrome. (Linux, v43). **EDIT:** Whoops, didn't see that you were testing on mobile.

Comment: Fixed backgrounds is a very GPU intensive task, so not all mobile browsers support them. Even desktop Firefox lags like crazy with some implementations of fixed image backgrounds on Linux distros.

Comment: so is there any other solution than this? like using some JavaScript library instead of just plain HTML css like I did?

Comment: Here's a good parallax example: http://codepen.io/keithclark/pen/JycFw

Comment: Hello, this is the same example I used to do my code, It is almost the same if you notice it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the position:fixed and try this:
https://jsfiddle.net/aatpa7qd/4/

```
$('body').scroll(function(){
  $("#title").css({"background-position":"center " +($('body').scrollTop()*0.65) + "px"});
});
```

Comment: the whole slight parallax effect is gone so this is not working :/

Comment: Are you looking for a fixed background? If so, you can just remove * 0.65 from the code.